# Select if then case with first record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you do something like this in SQL Server?

I want to select from a table which has some records with the same `product_id` in one column and a Y or N in another (in stock), and take the first one which has a Y where the product_id is the same, while matching the `product_id_set` from another table.

```
... , 
SELECT
    (SELECT TOP 1 
         (product_name), 
         CASE 
            WHEN in_stock = 'Y' THEN product_name 
            ELSE product_name 
         END
     FROM  
         Products
     WHERE
         Products.product_set = Parent_Table.product_set) AS 'Product Name',    
    ...
```

Sample data would be

```
product_set   in_stock   product_id   product_name
---------------------------------------------------
     1          N           12        Orange
     1          Y           12        Pear
     2          N           12        Apple
     2          N           12        Lemon
```

Output from product_set = 1 would be 'Pear' for example.

Comment: So there's some ambiguity in your question I need to clear up to give you a correct answer. If there are no records for a product id with an in_stock value of 'Y', should anything return? Secondly, if there are multiple rows with in_stock 'Y', do you care which one it picks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's kind of two solutions depending on the answer to the following question. If there are no records for a product id with an in_stock value of 'Y', should anything return? Secondly, if there are multiple rows with in_stock 'Y', do you care which one it picks?

The first solution assumes you want the first row, whether or not there is ANY "Y" value.

```
select *
from (select RID = row_number() over (partition by product_set order by in_stock desc) -- i.e. sort Y before N
      from Products) a
where a.RID = 1
```

The second will only return a value if there is at least one row with a 'Y' for in_stock. Note that the `order by (select null)` is essentially saying you don't care which one it picks if there are multiple in_stock items. If you DO care the order, replace it with the appropriate sort condition.

```
select *
from (select RID = row_number() over (partition by product_set order by (select null)) -- i.e. sort Y before N
      from Products
      where in_stock = 'Y') a
where a.RID = 1
```

I don't know what the structure of the "parent table" in your query is, so I've simplified it to assume you have what you need in `Products` alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(
             (
                 SELECT TOP 1 product_name
                 FROM Products
                 WHERE Products.product_set = Parent_Table.product_set
                       AND Products.in_stock = 'Y'
             ), 'Not in the stock') AS 'Product Name'
```